# How to get a dynamic height when clicking again on a toggled div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, height

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* SET VAR FOR IS OPEN */
    var isopen = 0;

    /* SHOW FIRST NEWS ON STARTUP EXTENDED */
    /* SET ALL .TRIGGER PARENT .CONTAINER TO FIXED HEIGHT WITH CUTTED CONTENT (OVERFLOW) */ 
    $('.trigger:not(:first)').css({
            height: "70",
            overflow: "hidden"
            }, 200 );

    /* CLOSE THE CLICKED ELEMENT */
    $('.trigger').click(function() {

        if (isopen == 0) {
            // SET ALL TRIGGER TO 70PX HEIGHT 
            $('.trigger').css({overflow: "hidden"}).animate({
                height: "70",
                }, 200 );
            $(this).animate({
                    height: "350",
                    }, 200 );
        } else {
            alert('this Alert shuld show up if isopen=1');
        }
    });
})
```

Its a news content of a website.
The user see three divs.
2 are cutted to 70px Height
The first news is extended to its original height.

after click the height: auto; does not work. So the height is set to 350px. How to get a dynamic height? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to 100% verify my answer as I would need a fiddle/plunker with your HMTL/CSS/JS to work with, but here is my suggestion that I think will help.

Rather than explicitly setting CSS styles to the elements via JavaScript, via methods like 'css(value, property)', instead add or remove classes to the elements via 'addClass()', 'removeClass()', or 'toggleClass()'.

New look JS:

```
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-closed');
}
```

New look CSS:

```
.trigger {
    // Your current UI component styling, but no height specified
}
.trigger.is-closed {
    height: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The difference here being, is that you're not trying to assert "height: auto" as an overriding style for "height: something else", you are simply adding and withdrawing the fixed height on open/close - which I would suggest is much less error prone much more likely to bring about the behaviour that you want.

Furthermore, this is also a good practice to follow in any event because of the following reasons:

- Separation of concerns, your styling belongs in your CSS files rather than JavaScript (i.e. component styles all together)
- Reusable code, these styles reflecting the "closed" state could be re-used across all instances of this UI component, as well as others components, rather than re-written every time in JS click handler functions
- Modifying CSS via jQuery functions such as 'css(property, value)' is a bad idea, it results in the styles added as inline styles in the DOM (e.g. style="height: 70px;") and this will take priority over other CSS, making managing your CSS harder and debugging presentation errors more difficult

This approach also has the added benefit of reducing the length and clarifying your JavaScript code significantly.

**Height Animation**

The above code will not provide the height animation that you currently have.

The solution here is to adopt a CSS transition approach rather than animating via JavaScript. Article: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

This will again mean that all of your component related styling will remain together in one place, but CSS animation also performs much better/renders faster than JavaScript animation does.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting css height in javascript is basically adding an element style tag to it, which will override the css file always due to the rendering rules of css.  If you set the value to an explicit height, to get it back to height: auto, you either have to write height: auto to it in the javascript or remove the style element you added completely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Writing "height: auto" will not work for any reason.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help any further without your code, height:auto should work if there's nothing not shown interfering (which there may very well be).  The answer Chris gave above is actually a fantastic answer to this, and I'd try and use what he described with the class toggling, its a much better practice then using css() in general.

Comment: Today: height:auto; worked for me. I dont know why.
But: max-height is needed.

Have to test chris method asap.